# Is it practical to do .net development using standard account in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, development-environment

Is it practical to do .net development using standard account in windows 7.  Do the tools even run in standard account, tools such as vs2010, sql server 2008, mysql, crystal reports?

Comment: being a developer and using standard account sucks!!! :)

Comment: That's why I ask if it is practical.  I know you must at least test your program in a standard account, but I really don't want UAC to popup every time I run the debugger, for example.  I also don't want to use administrator account if I can avoid it, to keep my computer's attack service to a minimum from virus and malware.

Comment: @ra70r Still have UAC enabled? What what? Only use a "safe" browser, don't run untrusted executables/macros, run behind a firewall, keep windows and apps updated and ... look ma, no viruses/worms! Also make sure to have backups and regular screening. Oh, yes, and *only elevate as needed*.

Comment: UAC is for sissies, I'm still using winxp :)  I'm just planning ahead. Ppl are upgrading to win7 because of the extra security, right?  Like I said, if it is practical to use standard account for development, why not enable UAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and I would argue it is better.

So many developers use/test in Visual Studio running as administrator, and then when they distribute to users, who will be restricted by UAC, there can be silly little things that creep up.

The only time you really need to run as administrator is when you have something specific that simply will not work without it. (One benefit is IIS attach, but with IIS Express, this will not be needed either).

I hear about people saying they need it, but I personally have not yet for every day normal programming.

Comment: Well, the IIS issue really forces most asp.net developers run vs in Admin mode. As for the deployment, just try run your programs as standard user before deploying (which is a must anyways, as running from VS will not give you the same paths/parameters as running it from explorer/shortcut).

Comment: @stefan - Cassini runs fine for me and i'm not running as an admin. If IIS is a pain for you then try using [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx).

Comment: Apart from IIS though, what can you not actually do in VS? I am curios myself as I have never had a problem and yet I hear people like you who recommend it!

Comment: Is it possible to attach to applications in order to debug them if running in standard mode? I think that was one issue that made me decide to ditch standard mode and run as an admin...can't quite remember though.

Comment: @slugster well, it depends how you are developing and what. it's sometimes very awkward to use webservices with cassini, also you really want to develop on something as close to the "real thing" because of server quirks. approx half of my web projects doesnt run as expected in cassini due to webservices etc. might be able to fix it but i dont see why i should spend time to try to fix something i really dont need.

Comment: I agree that for certain types of applications such as desktop apps, running in standard mode makes sense, since you want to simulate your user environment. But running in standard mode when developing enterprise apps / server apps when you know that the apps will run with administrator accounts in a production server environment just doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: @Wil see my comment to slugsters answer for my personal top reason to run as admin.

Comment: @Shan Plourde - You can attach to other processes fine... Just not ones running under a higher security context - that does require elevation.

Comment: @Wil - so IIS would be an example of that as referenced many times, or other apps running under an admin account I suppose. Noted, thx

Comment: I gave a +1. Even if some things need to be run as administrator, not all do (e.g. can elevate as needed). Whatever is done, it is very important to test as a *normal* user (and on the target platform(s)). Unfortunately I often run *VS* as administrator because it seems to be a requirement with VS2010 and COM building nonsense.

Comment: Can I have best of both worlds?  Run as standard user in daily use for extra security, but run VS as administrator.  Does that work?

Comment: @ra7or - throughout all the comments, only two things have come up as needing administrator - debugging other users and IIS. You can run fine as a regular user and the times you need to debug, or use iis, just elevate those few times.

Comment: Any experience running SQL Server, especially express or developer edition?  I probably should create a new question, but does Reporting Services work well with the new IIS Express?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do run. And you should do your development and testing in a standard account, because it will quickly show any UAC or privilege level problems you may have with your code (i.e. when accessing files, registry or other resources) which would not show up if you were developing using an administrative account.

Comment: You could just run the program as a standard user. The main problem is debugging as a standard account doesnt have priviliges to attach to native processes etc. You can get around and run the debugger by adding yourself to the debugger account but it wont solve the real problem anyways. IIS debugging and developing will demand Administrator account etc. Why bother running as a standard user, theres nothing standard in being an effective coder ;)

Comment: @Stefan - I debug fine as a standard user - any more information? As for IIS, I agree... With IIS Express this will become less important, but it is a issue for now...

Comment: @Wil i guess it depends what user runs the process you want to attach to.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to have administrator access. I've found some things don't work in standard mode unless I explicitly run applications as an administrator. This includes some development apps, some command line tools, etc. It may be possible but to minimize pulling out of hair, I'd run as a full admin!

Comment: If you want to run everything as full admin then you might as well move back to using Win95/98. Administrative level privileges were tightened in Win7 for a reason. Do you realise how many buggy applications have been released upon the world because the developers were too lazy to code (and run/test) as a standard user?

Comment: @slugster please enlighten us with this. I never heard of it being for development reason they dont want user to run as Admin, but more of a security reason. Which I fully support!

Comment: @slugster - are you saying that you would not have a development environment that emulates your production servers? What about WCF, Biztalk server, IIS on a production site, etc? Apps are commonly deployed and run under administration accounts. Wouldn't you want to have the same security credentials to test in your local development environments?

Comment: even if it is deployed on a server you don't run with administrative privileges unless you really have to. Every app i have ever written for a server (including web applications) runs as a limited privilege user. Web apps run as the lowly `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`, apps run under a user account created specifically for it **with only the privileges it needs**.

Comment: @slugster, that makes sense. I guess my gripe is just with debugging under VS.NET more than anything, probably